# How can I approve submitted request programmatically?

Tags: apex, trigger

I am new to salesforce development and I am trying to build up my skills by taking on some little tasks. I have a task thats bothering me. I have been asked to create a trigger on the contact object and on the creation of a new contact, an approval process should be automatically triggered to approve the contact and if the process is approved some changes to some custom fields need to be made.

I have written the trigger but on the creation of a new contact I get an error of no approval process found. How can I go about doing this the right way?

```
trigger contacttrigger on Contact (before insert, before delete) {
  
   for(Contact c : [Select Id, Active__c, Account.Total_Contacts__c from Contact ]){
       Boolean Active = c.Active__c;
       Decimal TotalAccounts = c.Account.Total_Contacts__c;
       if(trigger.isInsert){
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('Automatic submit.');
        req1.setObjectId(c.Id);
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
        if(result.isSuccess()){
            Active = true;
            TotalAccounts++;
        }
       }
      if(trigger.isDelete){
          TotalAccounts--;
      }
   }
}
```

Thats my code.

Comment: according to the error you wrote, the record doesn't meet the criteria for the approval process. You should check it and make sure it apply to the approval entry criteria, if it doesn't meet the criteria, don't submit it from the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple reasons why this could be happening:

1. As mentioned, you need to ensure that there is an approval process with **Entry Criteria** that the inserted or updated contact will meet.
2. Your code iterates over every single contact in the system every time a contact is inserted or updated, so you may be encountering previously approved contacts or contacts that otherwise won't meet the entry criteria.
3. Because its a *before insert* trigger, the record does not exist in the database at the moment the code is run, so it's not iterating over the contact being presently created.

To solve this

1. Filter the contacts by criteria that meet the entry criteria
2. Iterate only over contacts in the trigger
3. Change to an after trigger.

I will demonstrate 2 and 3 by changing your existing code to meet these improvements. Only the first two lines have been changed.

```
trigger contacttrigger on Contact (after insert, before delete) {

   for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
       Boolean Active = c.Active__c;
       Decimal TotalAccounts = c.Account.Total_Contacts__c;
       if(trigger.isInsert){
        Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest req1 = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
        req1.setComments('Automatic submit.');
        req1.setObjectId(c.Id);
        Approval.ProcessResult result = Approval.process(req1);
        if(result.isSuccess()){
            Active = true;
            TotalAccounts++;
        }
       }
      if(trigger.isDelete){
          TotalAccounts--;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Struggled with this.